# Unhandled Exception: type 'FetchLoadingState' is not a subtype of type 'FetchDataState' of 'state'

Tags: flutter, bloc, state-management

```
class FetchBloc extends HydratedBloc<FetchEvent, FetchDataState> {
  FetchBloc()
      : super(FetchDataState(fetchedData: const [], cityNames: const [])) {
    on<FetchWeather>(_fetchWeather);
    on<FetchCurrentLocation>(_fetchCurrentLocationWeather);
    on<RefreshData>(_refreshData);
    on<DeleteData>(_deleteData);
  }
  void _fetchWeather(FetchWeather event, Emitter<FetchState> emit) async {
    print(' loading state before');
    emit(FetchLoadingState());
    print("loading state after");
    event = await getCurrentWeather(event.cityName);
    if (event.data!.city == "city not found") {
      emit(
        FetchDataState(
          cityNames: List.from(state.cityNames!),
          fetchedData: List.from(state.fetchedData),
          snackBar: true,
          date: DateTime.now(),
        ),
      );
```

I am trying to emit a Loading state to display a refresh indicator on the screen while the data is being fetched.

Unhandled Exception: type 'FetchLoadingState' is not a subtype of type 'FetchDataState' of 'state'
this is the error i got.

I am new to state management

Comment: Can you provide FetchDataState & FetchLoadingState?

Answer (score 0):

Create a fetch_data_states.dart with:

```js
abstract class FetchDataState {}

class FetchLoadingState extends FetchDataState {}

class FetchedState extends FetchDataState {
  final List cityNames;
  final List fetchedData;
  final bool snackBar;
  final DateTime date;

  FetchedState({
    required this.cityNames,
    required this.fetchedData,
    required this.snackBar,
    required this.date,
  });
}
```

and then you emit only use these 2 states.

I'd recommend to also add an error state